# Why getting only values instead of keys and values in JSON response

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to retrieve data from database using an SQL native query but I am getting only values instead of keys and values in JSON response. How can i retrieve data with key and value in Json response?

Entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Table(name = "Products")
    public class ProductModel {
    
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Id
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "Category")
        private String category;
    
        @Column(name = "ProductName")
        @Lob
        private String productName;
    
        @Column(name = "Price")
        private int price;
    
        @Column(name = "Slider")
        private Boolean slider;
    
        @Column(name = "SpecialOffer")
        private Boolean specialOffer;
    
        @Column(name = "NewPrice")
        private int newPrice;
    
        @Column(name = "FullDescription")
        @Lob
        private String fullDescription;
    
        @Column(name = "Image")
        @Lob
        private String image;
    }
```

Repository:

```
    @Repository
    public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductModel, Long> {  

        @Query(value = "select id,image,product_name,price,new_price from products where slider is true", nativeQuery = true)
        List<String> getSliderContent();
    }
```

Service

```
    @Service
    public class ProductService {
 
        @Autowired
        private ProductRepository productRepository;
    
        public List<String> getSliderContent(){
            List<String> lstMovie = new ArrayList<>();
            lstMovie = productRepository.getSliderContent();
            return lstMovie;
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    @CrossOrigin("*")
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/products")
    public class ProductController {
        @Autowired
        private ProductService productService;
    
        @GetMapping("/sl")
        public List<String> getSliderContent(){
            List<String> ls = productService.getSliderContent();
            return ls;
        }
    }
```

I got data as json

```
["1, https://cdn.x-kom.pl/i/setup/images/prod/big/product-new-big, , 2021/10/pr_2021_10_8_14_22_27_699_08.jpg, Acer Swift 3 i5-1135G7/16GB/512/W11 Srebrny Intel Evo, 4800, 4500"]
```

Expected data in this format:

```
["id: 1, image: 'https://cdn.x-kom.pl/i/setup/images/prod/big/product-new-big, ,2021/10/pr_2021_10_8_14_22_27_699_08.jpg', product name: 'Acer Swift 3 i5-1135G7/16GB/512/W11 Srebrny Intel Evo', price: 4800, new_price: 4500"]
```

Can someone explain how to do it? I return data as `String` that's a problem, but how can i return `Json` object with native query?